# Libgdx Java - Size a table to the stage size (table's parent is not the stage)

Tags: java, libgdx

I would like to know how to size a table to the stage size knowing that the table's parent is not the stage but another table.

Here is the code I tried to use:
TableRoot is a table that will be added on the stage, method setFillParent(true) is called so that the table root has the same size as the stage.

```
public class StatusBoxesTable extends TableRoot {

        private static ArrayList<BATTLE_PARTY> sbPartiesOrdered = new ArrayList<BATTLE_PARTY>() {{
            this.add(BATTLE_PARTY.OPPONENT2);
            this.add(BATTLE_PARTY.OPPONENT);
            this.add(BATTLE_PARTY.PLAYER2);
            this.add(BATTLE_PARTY.PLAYER);
        }};

        // status box is a table
        private HashMap<BATTLE_PARTY, StatusBox> statusBoxes;

        //...

        // called every times the table needs to be updated
        private void refreshTable() {
            this.clear();
            for (BATTLE_PARTY party : StatusBoxesTable.sbPartiesOrdered) {
                Table table = new Table();
                table.setFillParent(true);
                this.addStatusBoxOnTable(table, party);
                if (BATTLE_PARTY.isPlayer(party))
                    this.add(table).expand().bottom().right();
                else
                    this.add(table).expand().top().left();
            }
        }

        private void addStatusBoxOnTable(Table table, BATTLE_PARTY party) {
            if (this.statusBoxes.containsKey(party)) {
                table.add(this.statusBoxes.get(party)).pad(this.getSBPad(party, Padding.TOP),
                    this.getSBPad(party, Padding.LEFT),
                    this.getSBPad(party, Padding.BOTTOM),
                    this.getSBPad(party, Padding.RIGHT));
            }
        }

        //...
    }
```

A status box is a table.

Each frame I refresh the StatusBoxesTable because the status boxes paddings can be changing overtime. I add 4 tables containing each other 1 status box in the StatusBoxesTable, I want all these 4 tables to have the same size as the stage but instead the tables are vertically aligned to the StatusBoxesTable.
This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Why do you put them all into a table if you don't want them to behave like they're in a table? Put them in a Stack.

Comment: Yes. I created a new type of table root containing a status box. And I created a new class: table root container that will enable to manage every table root with status box. The table root container adds each table root on the stage and it seems to work as i want